# How to fix special characters in R? REPLACEMENT CHARACTER

Tags: r

I have a problem with some data I´m working.
I extrac data from SQL SERVER and with R I work them, but for some fields of names, some names have instead of a letter the REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD)), is the one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OStt4.png)
I don´t want to use the replace function, to change the entire name.
Some ideas?

example the name MAGAÑA: MAGA�A

I use the following code to the connection and query:

```
library(odbc)
library(tidyverse)
library(dgof)
library(pROC)
library(ggplot2)
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(janitor)
library(DBI)
library(readxl)
library(data.table)

## Connection

conex1 <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                Driver = "SQL Server",
                Server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
                Database = "xxxxxxxx",
                UID = "xxxxxxx",
                PWD = "xxxxxxxxx",
                Port = 1433)

# Query

Fecha_nac<- dbSendQuery(conex1, "SELECT id_orden, 
fecha_nacimiento
  FROM zzgm_clientes_xxxxxxx") %>% 
dbFetch()
```

Comment: Can you show us a small bit of code you are using to extract the data?  It is hard to help you when I don't know what packages or functions you are using.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help.                                                                                'library(odbc)
library(tidyverse)
library(dgof)
library(pROC)
library(ggplot2)
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(janitor)
library(DBI)
library(readxl)
library(data.table)


conex1 <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                    Driver = "SQL Server",
                    Server = "xxx.xx.xx.xxx",
                    Database = "Xxxxxxxx",
                    UID = "xxxxxxxxx",
                    PWD = "xxxxxxxxxx",
                    Port = 1433) '

Comment: Then I do the consult-                                                                            
'Fecha_nac_Payjoy<- dbSendQuery(conex1, "SELECT id_orden, fecha_nacimiento
      FROM zzgm_clientes_payjoy") %>% 
  dbFetch()'

Comment: @MaximilianoDelaRosaBello it will be better to see this code in the question's body

Comment: it´s ready, thanks

Comment: Check the answer. If it helped - you can put a "tick" and accept the answer. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, `iconv` can help to you in this situation.

```
dataframe_with_right_symbols <- raw_dataframe %>%
      mutate_if(is.character, function(col) iconv(col, to="UTF-8"))
```